# EJB transaction timeout vs StuckThreadMaxTime

Tags: transactions, ejb, weblogic, middleware, osb

In Oracle Service Bus, I have a proxy service which processes huge data. I configured the transaction timeout of the corresponding EJB to 900 seconds. I expect the transaction not to be timed out for this time.

But I see below log in the server logs

```
####<Jun 25, 2015 5:58:04 AM PDT> <Error> <WebLogicServer> <nke-lnx-int-p001> <prdserver1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '32' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <1cbea9e26a1a3466:1932bd6d:14e2ab3c297:-8000-00000000000211a1> <1435237084076> <BEA-000337> <[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '21' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' has been busy for "645" seconds working on the request "Workmanager: WorkManager-proxy1, Scheduled=false, Started=true, Started time: 645788 ms
", which is more than the configured time (StuckThreadMaxTime) of "600" seconds.
```

If the transaction timeout is 28800 sec, shouldn’t the service wait for this complete time, why is the thread marked as stuck state within 600 Sec?

Answer (score 0):

Please log in to weblogic console in:

Home >Summary of Servers > Tuning Tab

```
Stuck Thread Max Time: decide it appropriately

Stuck Thread Timer Interval: decide it appropriately
```

and allocate a Work Manager for your proxy / business service.